# Allow user to share website link to a specific group

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, share

I have this development requirement:

On a website there is a link. When user clicks the link - it opens window (popup tab or in-page form - whatever) that allows user to SHARE current webpage to a specific facebook place - preferably one, specific group.

Example, lets say we have a webpage "AstroStuff" about astronomy that allows people to add their texts or images. There is also one facebook group "Astrolovers" for people fancied with astronomy - but not necessarily readers of that page.

After user adds some text or image, webpage should say: 
"Hey, you just added nice astronomy picture, why dont you share it to a facebook group Astrolovers?".

Something like this could pop up:

[image]

Is there any way for accomplishing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the Send dialog with the group id put into the `to` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

(The user will be able to remove the group and/or add other recipients – but that should not matter much, right?)